# TLS challenge with docker-compose: acme: error presenting token: timeout

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I'm running the basic TLS challenge docker example:

```yaml
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.4"
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.email=${SSL_EMAIL}"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ${DATA_FOLDER}/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

  n8n:
    image: mjysci/n8n:latest-rpi
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5678:5678"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.n8n.rule=Host(`${SUBDOMAIN}.${DOMAIN_NAME}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.n8n.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.n8n.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.n8n.tls.certresolver=mytlschallenge
      - traefik.http.middlewares.n8n.headers.SSLRedirect=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.n8n.headers.STSSeconds=315360000
      - traefik.http.middlewares.n8n.headers.browserXSSFilter=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.n8n.headers.contentTypeNosniff=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.n8n.headers.forceSTSHeader=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.n8n.headers.SSLHost=${DOMAIN_NAME}
      - traefik.http.middlewares.n8n.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.n8n.headers.STSPreload=true
    environment:
      - N8N_BASIC_AUTH_ACTIVE=true
      - N8N_BASIC_AUTH_USER
      - N8N_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD
      - N8N_HOST=${SUBDOMAIN}.${DOMAIN_NAME}
      - N8N_PORT=5678
      - N8N_PROTOCOL=https
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - WEBHOOK_TUNNEL_URL=https://${SUBDOMAIN}.${DOMAIN_NAME}/
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ${DATA_FOLDER}/.n8n:/home/node/.n8n
```

But when I'm running it says:

```
level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"<MY_DOMAIN>\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [<MY_DOMAIN>]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[<MY_DOMAIN>] [<MY_DOMAIN>] acme: error presenting token: timeout 2021-02-01 10:09:04.491784271 +0000 UTC m=+378.657940910\n" providerName=mytlschallenge.acme routerName=n8n@docker rule="Host(`<MY_DOMAIN>`)"
```

In the browser, the application is available and works well with HTTPS but it says the certificate isn't valid (obviously). What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'm having the same problem on some domains.
It looks like its a timeout.
i tried to restart traefik now. same issue again.

ps: add traefik in the title of the thread, you may gain more visibility and answers.

EDIT: I reverted to version 2.3.7 and it works again.
there must be a bug in 2.4 (latest)

i created an issue :
https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/7848

Comment: you are absolutely right! 2.4.whatever fails renewing the certificate because of a timeout. 2.3.7 does the job. THX!